$L=\left \{ \left \langle M,D \right \rangle : M=TM\, ,\, D=DFA\, ,\, L(D)\neq \emptyset\, ,\, L(M)\subseteq L(D)\circ L(D) \right \}\notin RE$
$L=\left \{ \left \langle M,D \right \rangle : M\, is\, a\, TM\, ,\, D\, is\, a\, DFA\, ,\, L(D)\neq \emptyset\, ,\, L(M)\subseteq L(D)\circ L(D) \right \}$
$L\notin R$ which can be shown for example with Turing reduction.
I thought that I build a recognizer to $L$, i.e showed that $L\in RE$, but there is some mistake that I don't see, because $L\in coRE$ (and there for $L\notin RE$).
Here is what I wrote:
Input = <M,D> s.t M = TM , D = DFA
1. run BFS scan on the states of D
2. if the BFS in step 1 didn't find accepting sates
3.    reject <M,D>
4. else
5.     build D', which will be a DFA for L(D)∘L(D)
6.     for i = 0 to ∞
7.         for j = 0 to i
8.             for every x∈Σ^j in lexicographical order:
9.                 run M on w for i steps
10.                 if M accepts w
11.                    run D' on w
12.                   if D' accepts w
13.                      accept

What is wrong with that ?
(This is a question from an exam on computability)

$\circ$ is the the sign for concatenation

@BaderAbuRadi I not sure, but I think there is some point in what you wrote. If $L(D) = \emptyset$ then the machine should accept if $L(M) = \emptyset$ and in my previous version, I wrote to reject all x, including the current input <M,D> which may be still in $L$. I think it can be solved via using the recognizer of $\overline{E_{TM}}$ but at this point I'm a bit confused

Note that $A\subseteq B$ iff $A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$. So it boils down to a nonemptiness check (given that we can complement and intersect) which we know is not decidable. Intuitively, to decide if a machine accepts some input is not possible as if it does not accept any input, we have to keep looking for an input and do not halt.

In the language's definition $L(D)\neq \emptyset$. Meaning every input <M, D> where D is empty should  be rejected. If $L(D)\neq \emptyset$ was not specified, then you need to consider the case of $L(D)= \emptyset$, but there is no need in the current version of the langauge.

@BaderAbuRadi So the line "reject al x" was correct if I understand properly what you wrote. I will put the previous version (mainly for my own clarity) if so.

Reject <M, D> and not "all x".

You are accepting as soon as you find a word that is in both $L(M)$ and $L(D) \circ L(D)$; that is, you are semideciding
$$\exists w. w \in L(M) \land w \in L(D) \circ L(D)$$
rather than
$$\forall w. w \in L(M) \to w \in L(D) \circ L(D)$$
These are of course not equivalent.

Thank you! The quantifier really helped. Is there some unformal explanation you can give to why this language is not recognizable ?

Rice's theorem. You said it yourself: "$L \notin R$ which can be shown for example with Turing reduction."
